# Rails Asset Pipeline: Getting raw data in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, asset-pipeline

This works well in development:

```
raw Rails.application.assets['path'].to_s
```

But in production it throws the following error:

> undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

All my assets have been precompiled.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @meagar Loading raw svg-html into a view.

Comment: ok `Rails.application.assets` is `nil`, but what is the value of `Rails.application`? What about this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34380753/rails-application-assets-is-nil-on-heroku-after-upgrade-sprockets-rails-to-3-0-0#34624267

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio That solved it. Thank you :)

Comment: @jonhue we are invincible :)